# Show that $(g\circ f)':[a,b] \to R$ is differentiable and find the derivative. (Chain Rule Proof)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know I probably shouldn't ask two questions in a short amount of time but this is a rather simple one.

Question: Suppose $f : [a, b] \to [c, d]$ and $g : [c, d] \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable on [a,b] and [c,d], respectively. Suppose $f' : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g' : [c, d] \to \mathbb{R}$ are also differentiable on [a,b] and [c,d], respectively. Show that $(g \circ f)':[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and find the derivative.

Note: I'm not sure how to make the composed function in MathJax so if anyone wants to edit that for me it would be much appreciated.

Anyways, as for the problem this looks very similar to the definition of the chain rule except you aren't give an $x_0 \in [a,b]$. So where do I begin this proof? I don't think I start with an arbitrary accumulation point of the set [a,b], but I'm not sure how else I relate the given information
.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $(g\circ f)' = (g'\circ f) \cdot f'$ is a product of two functions. A product of two differentiable functions is differentiable. $f'$ is differentiable, how about $g'\circ f$? Why is it differentiable?

Comment: By the chain rule? The composition of two differentiable functions is also going to be differentiable. Right?

Comment: @jlang There you go! Now you just need to calculate the derivative of $(g\circ f)'$.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was this simple, I just thought for some reason you need some element of the domain to apply the chain rule to a point rather than just the entire domain. But I'm guessing since the OP says its differentiable on the domain you can just go ahead and apply the chain rule to the domain?

Comment: @jlang That's precisely it. You can think of doing all these operations on every point in the domain.

Comment: Alright cool. Thank you for confirming my suspicion!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no "weirdness", the chain rule clearly states $\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x)) = f'(x)g'\left(f(x)\right)$.  Since $g$ is differentiable on the domain $[c,d]$ which is the range of $f$, this is clearly computable.  Further, $f'(x)$ is computable because the domain of $f'$ is $[a,b]$ the same as the domain of $g\circ f$.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. As I discussed with 5xum below I wasn't sure if you could go ahead and apply the chain rule to the entire domain or if you need a specific point from it, but with the knowledge of the entire domain being differentiable I realized (and he confirmed) you could just apply the chain rule to the entire domain.